# Error in MDW script from SQL tracer

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server MDW comes with built-in reports and I was curious about the underlying code behind the report to customize the reports. I used sql tracer to see what happens and this was the output containing errors. Was wondering if anyone could see what was wrong?

I get the following error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 26 An expression of non-boolean type
>   specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'.

```
DECLARE @ServerName varchar(max)
DECLARE @SelectedDatabaseName varchar(max)
DECLARE @snapshot_id int

SELECT TOP 1 @snapshot_id = snapshot_id FROM (

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 d.snapshot_id
FROM snapshots.disk_usage d, core.snapshots ss
WHERE ss.instance_name = @ServerName
AND ss.snapshot_id = d.snapshot_id
ORDER BY d.snapshot_id DESC
) AS q
ORDER BY snapshot_id ASC

SELECT
database_name,
CONVERT (datetime, SWITCHOFFSET (CAST (d.collection_time AS datetimeoffset), '+00:00')) AS collection_time,
d.snapshot_id,
((convert(dec (15,2),d.dbsize) + convert(dec(15,2),d.logsize)) * 8192 / 1048576.0) AS 'database_size_mb',
'reserved_mb' = (d.reservedpages * 8192 / 1048576.0),
'data_mb' = convert(dec(15,2),d.pages) * 8192 / 1048576.0,
'index_mb'= (d.usedpages - d.pages) * 8192 / 1048576.0,
'unused_mb' = ((convert(dec (15,2),d.reservedpages) - convert(dec(15,2),d.usedpages)) * 8192 / 1048576.0),
'unallocated_space_mb' = (
case
when d.dbsize &gt;= d.reservedpages
then (convert (dec (15,2),d.dbsize) - convert (dec (15,2),d.reservedpages)) * 8192 / 1048576.0
else 0
end)

FROM snapshots.disk_usage d, core.snapshots ss

WHERE database_name =@SelectedDatabaseName

AND d.snapshot_id &gt;= @snapshot_id
AND ss.instance_name = @ServerName
AND d.snapshot_id = ss.snapshot_id
ORDER BY collection_time asc
```

Comment: What kind of error, not work, syntax error, or return incorrect data?

Comment: will edit post. Sorry.

Comment: `d.dbsize &gt;= d.reservedpages` => `d.dbsize >= d.reservedpages`

Comment: Change `&gt;` to`>` and `&lt;` to `<`